# Issue with CSS transition on element shown with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a simple toggle plus sign that should trigger a div to appear and rotate into an X which can then be clicked to close the div.

Everything works as planned except there is no smooth transition in the rotation of the plus, it just appears already rotated.

If I remove the `display:none` from the `#showbox` div and remove `$("#showbox").show()`, the animation/transition works.  It's only if the div is hidden and then shown with `.show()` that it just rotates without animating.

I'm sure I can think of a workaround, I'm just wondering if anyone can explain why this might be happening

```js
$("#togglebox").click(function() {
  $("#showbox").show();
  $("#showbox .toggleplus").toggleClass("togglex");
});
```

```css
#showbox {
  background: #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.toggleplus {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all .5s;
  color:#111;
}

#showbox .toggleplus {
color:#FFF;
}

.togglex {
  transform: rotate(-46deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="togglebox">
  <p>LEARN MORE</p>
  <div class="toggleplus">+</div>
</div>

<div id="showbox">
  <div class="toggleplus">+</div>
  <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the plus sign in this code?

Comment: Wasn't really necessary to add all the html for the question, but I threw a simple `+` in there for clarification.

Comment: As you can see the first time the snippet is run and the `+` is clicked, it will not animate. On subsequent clicks it will.

Comment: Well, if we can't see the thing that is supposed to transition, it's hard to know what your issue is. I have added the same + sign in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the UI updates in a different thread than the JavaScript executes in and that UI thread executes faster than the JS.

You can fix this by adding a short delay, which forces the UI not to update until the function is complete.

```js
$("#togglebox").click(function(){
        $("#showbox").show();
        setTimeout(function(){
          $("#showbox .toggleplus").toggleClass("togglex");
        },20);
    });
```

```css
#showbox {
     background:#fff;
     width:500px;
      height:200px;
     display:none;
    }
    
    .toggleplus {
     float:right;
     width:30px;
     height:30px;
     transition:all .5s;
    }
    
    .togglex {
     transform: rotate(-46deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="togglebox">
        <p>LEARN MORE</p>
        <div class="toggleplus"></div>
    </div>
     
    <div id="showbox">
        <div class="toggleplus">+</div>
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
```

Another way to accomplish this with JQuery is to have the addition of the rotation class code added as a callback to the **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** method:

```js
$("#togglebox").click(function(){
        // Passing a function to the show method sets it up as a callback to
        // be executed after the show() animation is complete.
        $("#showbox").show(function(){
          $("#showbox .toggleplus").toggleClass("togglex");
        });
    });
```

```css
#showbox {
     background:#fff;
     width:500px;
      height:200px;
     display:none;
    }
    
    .toggleplus {
     float:right;
     width:30px;
     height:30px;
     transition:all .5s;
    }
    
    .togglex {
     transform: rotate(-46deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="togglebox">
        <p>LEARN MORE</p>
        <div class="toggleplus"></div>
    </div>
     
    <div id="showbox">
        <div class="toggleplus">+</div>
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured `setTimeout()` was the solution, thanks for the explanation as to why.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize `show()` also had a callback.